# putc giving segmentation fault?

Tags: c, file, file-handling

The following code is giving segmentation fault....Why ????? event tried with fputc

I think there might be a silly error i am not able to get..but don't have enogh time.

Please help...

```
   #include <stdio.h>

    int main () {

  //      system("sudo openssl enc -base64 -in file.txt -out file.txt.enc");

    FILE *fp,*fq;
    char ch;

    fp = fopen("file.txt.enc","r");
    fq = fopen("output.txt","w");

    while( (ch=fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
            putc(ch,fq);

    return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Make sure `fopen` worked and did not return a NULL pointer. Also accompany your `fopen`s with a `fclose` when done.

Comment: I guess this is the 20 th time seeing the same question

Comment: working fine on my compiler i got no issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You have to declare `ch` as `int`. Otherwise, the processing of the file will stop when the character *ÿ* appears. `char` can take only 256 different values, which is not enough for 256 different symbols + the `EOF` character. `EOF` is `-1`, which is equivalent to `4,294,967,295` when treated as an `int`, but it's equivalent to `255` when treated as a `char`. If your input file contains the character *ÿ* (essentially `-1` or `255` when treated as `signed`), the statement `ch == EOF` will become true and your `while` loop will break. This has **nothing** to do with your error, but it's important nonetheless...
2. If your program crashes, it tries to read from / write to the `NULL` pointer because the input file couldn't be read (doesn't exist) or the ouput file couldn't be written to (write protected).

Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    FILE *fp,*fq;
    int ch;

    if( (fp = fopen("file.txt.enc","r")) == NULL)
        return 1;

    if( (fq = fopen("output.txt","w")) == NULL)
        return 1;

    while( (ch=fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        putc((char) ch, fq);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I got the solution.It was actually a permission issue.There was noting to do with char or int.However as you have specified it may cause bug in future i will change it. (although it is working fine now).But i want to know one thing actually the input file being read here is actually an outcome of RSA Encryption.So will it work fine whether i would read it as character or int ???? I mean does encryption standard also encrypt the EOF character.

Comment: @Udit No, you really do have to use int. It is not working fine at the moment. Your code is broken as many have explained to you.

Comment: @Udit Gupta: The `EOF` character doesn't get encrypted. It's not part of the file. You should read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file). I've expanded my answer on why your code is faulty. Just write *AÿB* to a file and see what both versions make of it.

Answer (score 4):

Probably one of your `fopen` calls failed. You didn't bother to check whether or not they succeeded.

When `fopen` fails a null pointer is returned. If you try to use that subsequently then your program will likely bomb.

You will then have to fix the bug that Blagovest describes, and you should, of course, close your files.

Answer (score 2):

`fgetc` returns `int`, not `char`. The purpose of that is to be able to return `EOF` and distinguish that from a character that's read.

Just declare `ch` as an `int`.

Comment: tried but did not help.......also when i used `printf` its working fine even with `char ch`

Comment: You must declare `ch` as int. However, this bug would not explain seg fault as I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out and read my answer http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgetc/

```
     Fgetc() \\ returns a signed int value
```

and you have declared ch as char make it as int and try it out. it will work
Probably you have to check out what really the fopen is returning to you, may be its because fopen failed . its working fine on my gcc

Answer (score -1):

ch must be integer. See `man fgetc` and `man putc`.